# Is it necessary to use class based views in django with react-frontend application or we can work with functional view also for login authentication?

Tags: python, reactjs, django

I have gone through a few tutorials on user authentication in a Django + React web app. All of them simply use class based views in Django for login backend with react frontend. Any suggestion to work with functional views?

Comment: No, you can use either - React won't know how Django creates views it will only see the HTTP response

Comment: Can you refer a link for simple login page with django and react?

Answer (score 0):

Django's function- and class-based views are [essentially the same thing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/) in different form. They receive an [`HTTPRequest`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest) and return an appropriate [`HTTPResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse).

So, yes, anything that was solved using class-based views can be accomplished in function-based views, too.

I would suggest that you use [*Classy Class-Based Views*](https://ccbv.co.uk/) to explore what's happening "behind the scenes" for specific generic class-based views that were used in your tutorial.
This way you should be able to get a feeling what needs to be done to refactor it into a function-based view.

Comment: Can you refer a link for simple login page with django and react?

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to achieve. Are you using _Django REST Framework_ for your API? If so, have a look at the [ways of authentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) in their docs. Depending on which route you take, you will have to implement your views completely different.